# .htaccess not redirecting where I expect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

1- I wrote the following redirect expecting that when this url

"http://www.curtainrodstore.com/index.php?crn=234"

was entered it would redirect to

"http://www.curtainrodstore.com/product-category/curtains-drapery/shower-curtains/"

2- Instead it redirects to

"http://www.curtainrodstore.com/?crn=243"

3- Note the missing

"index.php"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^curtainrodstore.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} crn=243
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.curtainrodstore.com/product-category/curtains-drapery/shower-curtains/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule mod>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it is not working?

Here is an updated attempt list…

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#ATTEMPT 1
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^curtainrodstore.com [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} index\.php
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} crn=243
#RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.curtainrodstore.com/product-category/curtains-drapery/shower-curtains/ [R=301,L]
#ATTEMPT 2
#RewriteRule ^index\.php\?crn=243$ http://curtainrodstore.com/product-category/curtains-drapery/shower-curtains/ [R=301,L]
#ATTEMPT 3
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.curtainrodstore.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^crn=234$
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.curtainrodstore.com/product-category/curtains-drapery/shower-curtains/? [R=301,L]
#ATTEMPT 4
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^curtainrodstore.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^crn=234$
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://curtainrodstore.com/product-category/curtains-drapery/shower-curtains/? [R=301,L]
#ATTEMPT 5
#
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have tried the suggestion by Showdev it doesn't work either. It also takes me to "http://www.curtainrodstore.com/?crn=243".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?curtainrodstore.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php  [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} crn=234    [NC]
RewriteRule .* product-category/curtains-drapery/shower-curtains/? [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://www.curtainrodstore.com/index.php?crn=234`

To:

`http://www.curtainrodstore.com/product-category/curtains-drapery/shower-curtains/`

For silent mapping, remove `R=301` from `[R=301,L]`

**Make sure browser's cache is cleared before any test**

Comment: @faa Can you shed some light on what may have been going wrong before?

Comment: 1) It is same domain 2) `Options +FollowSymlinks` is critical. 3) In this case %{REQUEST_URI} is more reliable than %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.

Comment: Thanks, Faa. DigitalAcid... please consider an upvote if you haven't already.